# CKEditor HTML tags appearing

Tags: html, ckeditor

Hello I am using CKEditor on my site and the problem is when a user posts their content it is posted with HTML tags. Have looked everywhere but cannot find a way to make them go away. I want whatever a user types to appear as the exact same plain text, html tag free, EXACTLY like I am doing on Stackoverflow posting this question. My questions will appear as text, no html tags. Here is my code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Content</label>
                <textarea name="content[text]" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content[text]' );
                </script>

            </div>
```

Comment: CKEditor is for rich text input. If you strip HTML tags, it'll lose formatting. If you don't want HTML tags you could use a regular text box then strip out the tags on the server side, which is probably more secure anyway.

Comment: @amphetamachine I simply want my users to be able to format and edit their text (bold etc) just like posting a question on Stack OVerflow. I thought CkEditor was the correct route I guess not.

Comment: StackOverflow uses a variant of [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for its questions. This is different from rich text, and not something I believe CKEditor can do. You'll want to find a web input that understands markdown. You'll still have to parse the markdown on the server side if you're going to display it.

Comment: @amphetamachine thank you! Will look into it (: